# Python Generate a big text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Using Python 3.8, I am trying to generate a big text file filled by random alphabets and or letters.
Here is the code that does not do anything, and I am not too sure why.

```
def generate_big_random_letters(filename,size):
    
    import random
    import string

    chars = ''.join([random.choice(string.letters) for i in range(size)]) #1


    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(chars)
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_big_random_letters("temp_big_letters.txt",1024*1024)
```

Comment: What does "random alphabets and or letters" mean?

Comment: In Py3.x there is `string.ascii_letters` instead of `string.letters`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If so, add them to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`string.ascii_letters`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_letters) and [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits):

```
import random
import string

def generate_big_random_letters(filename, size):
    chars = ''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for i in range(size)])  # 1

    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        f.write(chars)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    generate_big_random_letters("temp_big_letters.txt", 1024 * 1024)
```